# Запрос на исправление ошибки в тексте

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Требуется найти готовый сервис. Реализация может быть как для `Angular` (`TypeScript`), так и обычный `JS` модуль.

Задача: Необходимо получить от пользователей отзыв с просьбой исправить текст на сайте. Для упрощения взаимодействия пользователей с разработчиками требуется механизм выделения текста и предложения варианта исправления.

Алгоритм:

1. Выделение текста с ошибкой
2. Нажатие горячих кнопок (CTRL\SHIFT\ALT + что-нибудь)
3. Появляется окно с текстовым полем, куда пользователь вводит исправленный вариант текста
4. Данные отправляются на сервер, где администратор может просмотреть запросы

Найдены такие примеры ([1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-feedback) и [2](http://jacobscarter.github.io/angular-feedback/#/)), но в них отсутствует вызов по горячим клавишам и выделяется не текст, а HTML элемент. Необходимо что-то похожее на [это](https://mistape.com/).

Comment: напишите свою реализацию, тот алгоритм, который вы описали не кажется сложным :)

Comment: Ну да, но просят поддерживаемую на стороне библиотеку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так примерно? :)

Upd: припаял jsonstore.io, сохраненные данные можно глянуть [тут](https://www.jsonstore.io/36714770fba88322c1ab00e45dd7b38f46a873180320ad3ac5850a82a4d8118d/record)

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (!e.ctrlKey || e.code !== "Enter")
    return;
  let form = document.querySelector('div.form');
  form = form || document.createElement('div');
  form.classList.add('form');
  form.innerHTML = `
    <textarea>${getSelectionText()}</textarea>
    <button onclick="submit()">send</button>
  `;
  document.body.append(form)
})

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function submit() {
  let form = document.querySelector('div.form');
  post(form.querySelector('textarea').textContent);
  form.remove();
}

function rnd(i) {    
    var rnd = '';
    while (rnd.length < i) {
        rnd += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    }
    return rnd.substring(0, i);
};

function post(text) {
  let jsonstore = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/36714770fba88322c1ab00e45dd7b38f46a873180320ad3ac5850a82a4d8118d/';
  
    let key = rnd(55);
    fetch(jsonstore + 'record/'+key, {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: 'text'}),
    });
 
}
```

```css
.form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  top:50vh;
  left:50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding: 4px;
}

textarea {
  width: 190px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Выделить текст здесь и нажать ctrl+enter
```

Comment: Ну вообще мне нужен был готовый сервис, но ладно, за работу просто отмечу :)

Comment: @Komdosh сервис в интернете?

Comment: ага, именно в интернете

Comment: @Komdosh то есть чтобы он у себя эти данные собирал? тогда можно прикрутить какой-нибуть https://www.jsonstore.io/ и успокоиться

Comment: ну да, самописно получается так, вы правильно говорите, проблема просто в том, что принимать эти запросы будут не разработчики, в общем требуется сервис, который просто позволит выделить текст и отправить на доработку, где админ (не разработчик) возьмёт этот фидбэк и исправит текст у себя. Вы это реализовали верно, так что вопрос в принципе снимается

Comment: @Komdosh давайте такой запилим сами =)

Comment: @Komdosh прикрутил сохранение в jsonstore =)